# "Undefined is not a function and "Cannot read property 'init' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am trying to get this javascript code to open/close a megamenu section to work with Wordpress:

It does work on a html template. I have also created a Walker that works.

```js
var swMegaMenu = (function() {

 var $listItems = $( '#sw-hrmenu > ul > li' ), // Uncaught TypeError: Undefined is not a function
  $menuItems = $listItems.children( 'a' ),
  $body = $( 'body' ),
  current = -1;

 function init() {
  $menuItems.on( 'click', open );
  $listItems.on( 'click', function( event ) { event.stopPropagation(); } );
 }

 function open( event ) {

  if( current !== -1 ) {
   $listItems.eq( current ).removeClass( 'sw-hropen' );
  }

  var $item = $( event.currentTarget ).parent( 'li' ),
   idx = $item.index();

  if( current === idx ) {
   $item.removeClass( 'sw-hropen' );
   current = -1;
  }
  else {
   $item.addClass( 'sw-hropen' );
   current = idx;
   $body.off( 'click' ).on( 'click', close );
  }

  return false;

 }

 function close( event ) {
  $listItems.eq( current ).removeClass( 'sw-hropen' );
  current = -1;
 }

 return { init : init };

})();
```

and(snippet in footer):

```js
<script>
   (function($) { // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of undefined
    swMegaMenu.init();
   })(jQuery);

</script>
```

Any idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: have you imported jquery library?

Comment: I updated the question now :) its abit more complex. I think Wordpress has jQuery already installed.

Comment: Try changing `(function()` to `(function($)` and the ending `()` to `(jQuery)`

Comment: Are you sure the first script executed on the page correctly? Simply seems like `swMegaMenu` is undefined...

Comment: @rnevius it did work! :) Thank you! Now everything works as it should!

Comment: @Stokken I've written up an answer with more of an explanation. Check out my answer, and let me know if you have any questions. It would be great if you could upvote/select it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do it like this:

```
        var swMegaMenu = (function () {

        var $listItems = $('#sw-hrmenu > ul > li'), // Uncaught TypeError: Undefined is not a function
            $menuItems = $listItems.children('a'),
            $body = $('body'),
            current = -1;


        function open(event) {

            if (current !== -1) {
                $listItems.eq(current).removeClass('sw-hropen');
            }

            var $item = $(event.currentTarget).parent('li'),
                idx = $item.index();

            if (current === idx) {
                $item.removeClass('sw-hropen');
                current = -1;
            }
            else {
                $item.addClass('sw-hropen');
                current = idx;
                $body.off('click').on('click', close);
            }

            return false;

        }

        function close(event) {
            $listItems.eq(current).removeClass('sw-hropen');
            current = -1;
        }

        return { init: init };

    })();

    swMegaMenu.initialize = function()
    {
        $menuItems.on('click', open);
        $listItems.on('click', function (event) { event.stopPropagation(); });
    }
```

And in the footer:

```
<script>
        (function($) { // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of undefined
            swMegaMenu.initialize();
        })(jQuery);

</script>
```

I am not able to verify the code as no markup is provided, but it should be something like this.

Answer (score 0):

You're using WordPress, which includes jQuery in [noConflict() mode](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) by default. In the `noConflict()` mode, the global `$` shortcut for jQuery is not available.

As a result, you're going to need to change `(function()` to `(function($)` and the ending `()` to `(jQuery)`.

Read more about `noConflict()` wrappers in [the WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers).